# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. with Items

Tags: reactjs, key, prop

I am stuck due to the following error :
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I have in my code :

```
const [watchnfts, setwatchNfts] = useState([])
......
const items = await Promise.all(data.map(async i => {
      let item = {
        key : i.tokenId.toNumber(),
        tokenId : i.tokenId.toNumber(),
        tokenURI : i.tokenURI,
        watch_Model : i.watch_Model,
        watch_serialnumber : i.watch_serialnumber,
        brand :i._brand,
        mintedBy : i.mintedBy,
        currentOwner : i.currentOwner,
        previousOwner : i.previousOwner,
        price : i.price.toNumber(),
        numberOfTransfers : i.numberOfTransfers,
        forSale : i.forSale,
        destroyed :i.destroyed,
        accountAddress : signer.getAddress(),
      }
      return item
    }))
    console.log('items: ', items)
    setwatchNfts(items)
```

and I get the error when I try to use that :

```
  <MDBCardGroup>
    <MDBRow>
     {watchnfts.map((watch) => {
      return (  <></>    
             /*   <MyWatchNFTCard
                    watch={watch}
                  />*/
      );
    })}
    </MDBRow>
  </MDBCardGroup>
```

I understood I  hould set a key value but i do not understand nor how, nor where
Can someone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

For keys, You should use Your own unique identifier (id).

```
watchnfts.map((watch) => {
  return (
    <MyWatchNFTCard watch={watch} key={watch.id} />
   )
});
```

When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, You may use the item index as a key as a last resort:

```
watchnfts.map((watch, index) => {
  return (
    <MyWatchNFTCard watch={watch} key={index} />
   )
});
```

In other cases, such as: you want to have side-by-side elements, You can wrap them with `React.Fragment`:

```
watchnfts.map((watch) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
      <MyWatchNFTCard watch={watch} />
      <SomethingElse />
    </React.Fragment>
   )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested add any key to `MyWatchNFTCard`

```
<MDBCardGroup>
  <MDBRow>
    {watchnfts.map((watch) => {
      return <MyWatchNFTCard watch={watch} key={watch.id} />;
    })}
  </MDBRow>
</MDBCardGroup>
```